# Sum rule of Dini derivative

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Lower Dini derivative of function F at point x in direction d is defined by
$$DF(x):=\liminf\limits_{h\to 0^+}\frac{F(x+hd)-F(x)}{h}.$$
Consider two functions F and G, we have
$$D(F+G)(x) \geq DF(x)+DG(x). \quad(1)$$

> Question: if G is differentiable, is the following true?
>   $$D(F+G)(x) = DF(x)+DG(x). \quad(2) $$

Answer: Yes

Proof: Assume $DG(x) \to g(x)$ since $G$ is differentiable. Using (1) we have
$$D(F+G)(x) \geq DF(x)+DG(x)= D(F(x)) + g(x). \quad (3)$$
Furthermore, using $ D(-G(x))=-g(x)$, we have
$$D(F(x)) = D((F(x)+G(x)) +(- G(x)))$$ 
         $$  \geq D(F(x)+G(x)) + D(-G(x)) $$
         $$ =D(F(x)+G(x)) - g(x).$$
Hence
$$D(F+G)(x) \leq D(F(x)) + g(x) \quad(4).$$
Combing (3) and (4), we have
$$D(F+G)(x) = DF(x)+g(x).$$

Comment: The guy is called Dini...

Comment: Only G is differentiable. If both are differentiable, my understanding is that the equality holds.

Comment: No, I haven't tried anything - just curious.

Comment: I answered my own question.